# Remote host closed connection during handshake

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, agent

I have a java agent in my Notes Database which executes example code for sending SMS to a defined Number. So there is an API which is used from the service https://websms.com/. Unfortunately the Remote is closing the connection with the failure: "Remote host closed connection during handshake". I assume that it has something to do with the SSL certificate or something.

Does anyone have a clue about where to enable a Domino Server to use SSL or something?

We are using this service: https://websms.com/

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a matter of "enabling a Domino Server to use SSL".  Your code is written in Java, therefore it is the embedded JVM within Domino that is doing the networking. That is separate from the Domino server's own native networking support.

The first thing you need to do is figure out why the handshake is failing. 
It might be a protocol issue rather than a certificate issue. E.g., if the endpoint and the JVM have no ciphers in common, that will fail; if the endpoint is requiring TLS 1.1 or above and the JVM does not support anything above TLS 1.0, that will fail. But if it is a certificate issue, then see this [IBM Technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21588966/).

As far as figuring out the handshake problem goes, the first step in this is usually getting in touch with the support staff for the endpoint that you are connecting to and asking what their SSL connection requirements are, and asking if their logs show where the handshake is failing. If you have to do the analysis on your end, the first step is generally to set -Djavax.net.debug=all in the JVM's startup properties. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) for some basic information. And see [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21377792) for details on how to set JVM properties on a Domino server.

Comment: Can you say which Java Version is used in Lotus Notes 9? The developers of the webSMS service recommend to install "Java Cryptography Extension (JCE)". Is that even possible on a Domino Server?

Comment: Notes 9 is still running Java 6. That's unfortunate, but I believe Java 6 can support all up-to-date SSL ciphers and protocols.And yes, you can install JCE, though I believe it's already there.

Comment: Ok. Trying to install the JCE, but the installation instruction do not give me a hint on where to put the files as the directories doesn´t exist on our domino server:
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS8JFY_7.5.0/com.ibm.lmt75.doc/com.ibm.license.mgmt.security.doc/lmt_scr_downloading_installing_jce_policyfiles.html

Comment: Use dir /s *.jar (or equivalent for your Domino server's operating system) to find all jar files in folder underneath your Domino Data folder. It will be one of those folders.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not have any effect. Maybe I have to dig deeper into setting Notes.ini parameter such as defining which encryption method to use.